# How to read and display multiple values from xml file?

Tags: php, xml

Here are my files:

example.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf_8"?>
<available_technologies>
  <available_technology>
    <Opportunity_type>
    <item><value>Licensing</value></item>
        <item><value>Distribution</value></item>
    </Opportunity_type>
 </available_technology>
    enter code here
</available_technologies>
```

test.php

```
<?php

function ibportal_cron(){
    $xml=simplexml_load_file("example.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
    foreach($xml->children() as $child)
    {
        $childArray = (array)$child;
        echo "Opportunity Type :" .$childArray['Opportunity_type'] . "<br/>";
    }
}
?>
```

Thank you.

There is no error message but i cannot display values to the browser using echo or print.

Comment: Welcome. To ask [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), please read [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Please state: 1) What the problem is. 2) Any Error Messages

Answer (score 0):

```
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('simple.xml');
    $values = $xml->available_technology->Opportunity_type->item;
    $numberOfItems = count($values);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $numberOfItems; $i++) {
        echo "Opportunity Type :" . $values[$i]->value . "<br/>";
    }
```